# Center image in a square column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to make a few boxes with logo images that are centered. And I tried doing it with padding, just placing an image inside a column, centering it and adding top and bottom padding. But the thing is, I'll have a few of those boxes inside the grid with different size images and that'll end up looking messy. Is there another way for me to do this?

Here's an image of the box I'm trying to make:

[image]

And here's the rough outline of my code:

```css
.col-lg-6 {
  background-color: #8dc63f;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered this? Don't have time for a full answer
http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative/absolute position pairing with transition settings as shown in this snippet:

```css
.col-lg-6 {
  background-color: #8dc63f;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
</div>
```